# Breaking Uniquely decipherable codes.

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to decode a message that has been encoded using a Uniquely Decipherable Code without knowing the code that is used.
If it is possible, what is the time complexity?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on crypto.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

No. $0\mapsto 0$, $1\mapsto 1$ and $0\mapsto 1$, $1\mapsto 0$ are two uniquely decipherable codes. How would you know if $10110100$ stands for $10110100$ or $01001011$?